# Container crashes after one hour due to OOM

Tags: apache-spark, docker, mesos, dcos, docker-container

i'm running spark using docker on DC/OS. When i submit the spark jobs, using the following memory configurations

Driver 2 Gb

Executor 2 Gb

Number of executors are 3.

The spark submit works fine, after 1 hour the docker container(worker container) crashes due to OOM (exit code 137). but my spark logs shows that 1Gb+ of memory is available.

The strange thing is the same jar which is running in the container , runs normally for almost 20+ hours in the standalone mode.

Is it the normal behaviour of the Spark contianers, or is there Something im doing wrong.Or are there any extra configuraton do I need to use for the docker container.

Thanks

Comment: After monitoring the docker container stats using the 'docker stats' the docker memory Usage shows the memory is 100% utilized and crashing the docker container.

Comment: So that does mean it is a valid crash, now check the process inside container and use JMX or however you monitor the application.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I have a similar issue. Have you looked at the cache/buffer memory usage on the OS?

Using the command below you can get some info on the type of memory usage on the OS:

```
free -h
```

In my case the buffer / cache kept on growing until there was no more memory available in the Container. In my case the VM was a CentOS machine running on AWS and it crashed entirely when this happened.

Comment: The same behaviour is observed in my case.

Comment: Heya, in my case I was able to fix the container OOM crash by giving more memory for the container and less memory to the spark considering JVM usage in observation.

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried that as well but it still kept on crashing for me.. The JVM usage is not the issue actually. I kept a close eye on that and it didn't go outside of the boundaries that I set. The non JVM memory usage seems to be the problem..

Comment: are you persisting and RDD. If not reduce the storage fraction and give a shot

Comment: We are not persisting an RDD. I initially thought that was the issue but I actually call `unpersist` in order to prevent storing anything. Although I can see that during the shuffle actions I can see that there are some temp files written. Maybe the problem lies in writing those temp files. I can see that the buffer / cache gets exhausted on the Docker host. It just never gets free'd up.

Answer (score 0):

Is your spark calling REST end point, if yes, try closing connections